# What sequence of cross overs to follow Flash s04e08 to Flash s04e09?

Tags: arrowverse, the-flash, arrow, crossovers

I was trying to watch s04e08 of The Flash and I realised that the storyline was based on something that began from another CW show. I've seen this before but, it began with The Flash so it was easier to follow. I checked The Arrow s06e08 and it seemed to be another continuation. What's the cross over sequence to follow whats happening on The Flash?

Answer (score 4):

The order is as follows:

1. Supergirl [S3E8 Crisis on Earth-X Part-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crisis_on_Earth-X)
2. Arrow [S6E8 Crisis on Earth-X Part-2](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Crisis_on_Earth-X,_Part_2)
3. Flash [S4E8 Crisis on Earth-X Part-3](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Crisis_on_Earth-X,_Part_3)
4. Legends of tomorrow [S3E8 Crisis on Earth-X Part-4](http://arrow.wikia.com/wiki/Crisis_on_Earth-X,_Part_4)

Then watch Flash Episode 9